# Como abrir apenas um form mesmo clicando várias vezes C#

Tags: c#, windows

Boa tarde,
Estou fazendo um Quiz no Windows Form,e sempre que se clica numa resposta muda para o próximo form,com o seguinte código:

```
 Async void Proximo()

{

  await Task.Delay(100);

  this.Close();

  Form2 form = new Form2;

  form.Show();

}

private void button1_Click(object sender , EventArgs e)   

 {            
                                                       Proximo() ;      
                             }
```

Só que se eu der um duplo/triplo...clique,vai abrir duas/três vezes o mesmo form.Como faço para resolver isso?Mesmo dando um triplo clique abra apenas um único form?

Comment: não deveria usar async apenas para abrir outro form, menos um delay pra atrasar algo... você também pode usar ShowDialog que faz o form abrir de forma restrita e retornar um DialogResult...

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente você teria que verificar se o form já se encontra aberto:

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Count() > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("O Form2 já está aberto!");
}
else
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: No caso Form2 seria o nome do form.

Answer (score 1):

Check instance. Se existir, traga para frente e maximize.

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Count() > 0)
{
      Application.OpenForms["Form1"].BringToFront();
      Application.OpenForms["Form1"].WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
else
{
      Form1 frmForm1 = new Form1();
      frmForm1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:
var frmInicio = new frmInicio();
frmInicio.ShowDialog();